# Derivative of $f(t) = t + 2t^2\sin(\frac{1}{t})$ for $t \not= 0$?

Tags: calculus

This is part of a larger problem, and when I look at solutions for the problem they say that $f'(t) = 1 + 4t\sin(\frac{1}{h}) - 2\cos(\frac{1}{t})$, where I calculate that $f'(t) = 1 + 4t\sin(\frac{1}{h}) + 2t^2\cos(\frac{1}{t})$. Am I somehow taking the derivative incorrectly, or is there something else that I'm missing? I'm primarily worried about $f$ over $(-1,1)$, if that's relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solutions is right, you are wrong.

Comment: Where did $h$ come from?

Comment: @YiyuanLee, apparently (s)he's talking of $\;f'(h)\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(2t^2\sin\frac1t\right)'=4t\sin\frac1t+2t^2\left(-\frac1{t^2}\right)\cos\frac1t=4t\sin\frac1t-2\cos\frac1t$$

by the product rule for derivatives and the Chain Rule.

Comment: Ah, okay. Whoops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main part is deriving $2t^2 \sin\left(\frac1t\right)$.

Using $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$, you get that the derivative is $4t\sin \left(\frac1t\right) + 2t^2\left(\sin\left(\frac1t\right)\right)'$. The problematic part equals (using $(f\circ g)'= f'\circ g \cdot g'$
$$\left(\sin\left(\frac1t\right)\right)'= \cos\left(\frac1t\right)\cdot \frac{-1}{t^2},$$
so the end result for the original function $f$ is
$$f'= 1+4t\sin \left(\frac1t\right) - 2\cos\left(\frac1t\right)$$